# migration from ivy to gradle issues

Tags: gradle, ivy

I am moving from Ivy to grade.

In ivy I was able to have a property file that contained all my dependencies' versions.

Also when publishing I updated this file.

This is sort of central control of versions. Very comfortable. For example:

Versions.properties:

---

```
  log4j.ver=1.14
  commons-lang.ver=1.1
```

And ivy.xml:

---

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency org="log4j" module="log4j" ver="log4j.ver"/>
  </dependencies>
```

I can to the same in gradle but properties are said to be deprecated soon. Any equivalent concept in gradle?

Another issue is the ability to resolve dependencies in workspace. I know that there is the

```
  dependencies{
   compile project(':shared')
  }
```

Syntax, but I want the dependency to be flexible. If the project is in the  workspace, resolve it. Otherwise, download it from archives.

How to achieve this behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should have been two separate questions. Anyway:

ad 1) All that was deprecated is *dynamic properties*, i.e. introducing new properties with `foo = "bar"`. Instead, it's now `def foo = "bar"`, or, if the property needs to be accessible from other build scripts, `ext.foo = "bar"`. (This change will allow Gradle 2.x to fail if a property is misspelled; Gradle 1.x will at least give a deprecation warning.)

Note that nothing changes on the consumer side, i.e. the property can still be accessed via its simple name (e.g. `println foo`). Note that it should *not* be accessed via `ext.foo`, even though this will work in some cases.

ad 2) This isn't currently a first-class feature, but can be achieved with some effort. (See https://github.com/pniederw/elastic-deps for a proof-of-concept, and https://github.com/prezi/pride for an early version of a more serious implementation). I expect this to become a first-class feature in the 2.x timeframe.